# Different S3 buckets for staging app vs. production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have a Rails app that uses Amazon S3 to store Paperclip attachments. My `database.yml` file specifies different S3 buckets for development, test, and production.

I have two apps on Heroku - a production app and a 'staging app' for testing code on the platform pre-launch.

The current system has an important flaw - it uses the same S3 bucket for staging and production. How can I set up my system so it uses different buckets depending essentially on whether I write `git push production master` or `git push staging master`?

Comment: how do you write your paperclip conf?

Comment: Apnea, what file are you talking about?

Comment: in your models, how do you pass your s3 config to paperclip?

Comment: @apneadiving - In each model that has an attachment, I have the line `has_attached_file :whatever, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml", :path => "/whatever/:style/:id/:normalized_file_name"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heroku permits you to configure anything you like via persistent environment variables that every dyno/process in an application gets started with. Environment variables are not shared between staging and production versions of the same application. Take advantage of this.

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
  :styles => ...,
  :path => ...,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'], # <--- over here
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
  }
```

Then:

```
# Configure the "staging" instance
$ heroku config:add \
    RACK_ENV=production \
    S3_KEY=my-staging-key \
    S3_SECRET=my-staging-secret \
    S3_BUCKET=my-staging-bucket \
    --app my-staging-app-name

# Configure the "production" instance
$ heroku config:add \
    RACK_ENV=production \
    S3_KEY=my-production-key \
    S3_SECRET=my-production-secret \
    S3_BUCKET=my-production-bucket \
    --app my-production-app-name
```

Note that each instance of your application has a `RACK_ENV=production`. Don't use Rails environments for differentiating between instances of your application. Rather, your application should expect that environment variables be used to configure instance-specific aspects.

Comment: Yes, I set the `RACK_ENV=production` in the "staging" instance. This is because, on Heroku, you can use the environment variables for all of your configuration. You do not need the help of Rails environments for this. In your `production.rb` you can of course set a property based on the presence, absence, or value of an environment variable, and this is what you should do in your Heroku "staging" environment.

Comment: Thanks for this super helpful answer!  My question is when I try to change the environment by using RACK_ENV=development and RAILS_ENV=development, I keep getting errors that says 'Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch,' why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Set config:add RACK_ENV=staging on your staging box, and then in your code you can specify the bucket depending on the environment. Eg:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => ...,
    :path => ...,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'your_prod_bucket',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
  else
    has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => ...,
    :path => ...,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'your_staging_bucket',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }

  end
```

This heroku post also seem to suggest that you can achieve this simply by using different s3 credentials for staging and production. I'm guessing you'd have to do some configuration on amazon's side as well.  Anyways, take a look to see if it helps.
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I'd store the credentials in config/environments/ and avoid the conditional logic that would be potentially scattered throughout the code.